# Predict Time of projectile flight

Tags: mathematics

I am trying to matemathically predict how long will projectile fly until it reach 
 the target. I am trying to implement this formula:

**t = [V * sin(α) + √(V * sin(α))² + 2 * g * h)] / g**

where I know V (velocity of projectile) , α (angle of launch) , h (height of launch) The problem is it shows some weird results. I am not sure what is wrong (using ue4):

```
float Time = Velocity * FMath::Sin(AngleDeg) + FMath::Sqrt(FMath::Square(Velocity * FMath::Sin(AngleDeg)) + (2.f * Gravity * Height));
Time /= Gravity;
```

For example this test inputs:
        Gravity = 9.8;
        Height = 10;
        Velocity = 10;
        AngleDeg = 10; 
shows 0.97 seconds but theresult should be 1.61 according this calculator: https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/projectile-motion ... When I try different inputs the result is always wrong... I also got the formula from this website so not sure what's wrong. Thanks for any advice

Comment: Where in this formula does your target 's position or offser from the firing point occur?

Comment: does FMath:Sin accept degrees or radians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have **velocity** and **angle**, you can calculate \$v_x\$ and \$v_y\$.
You dont need \$v_x\$ though.

$$v_y = v \cdot sin \space \alpha $$

**Make sure that you use the right units. If `Sin` accept radians, don't pass degrees there.**

Then, using \$v_y\$, \$h\$ and \$a\$, you calculate flight time. You need to solve the equation:

$${at^2 \over 2} + v_yt + h = 0$$

Check your \$Y\$ axis. I assume that it goes up. **So acceleration is negative. If you have \$g > 0\$, then you should have \$a=-g\$**.

$$t_1, t_2 = {-v_y \pm \sqrt {{v_y^2} - 2ah} \over a}$$

Omit the negative root and you get

$$t = {-v_y - \sqrt {{v_y^2} - 2ah} \over a} = {v_y + \sqrt {{v_y^2} + 2gh} \over g}$$

It works:

[image]
[image]

If you fire from negative heights, be ready to get 2 positive roots, 2 negative roots or no roots at all.

Comment: It appears there is some problem with sin(a) . For example FMath::Sin(10); returns -0.54 but should 0.73 . Might be problem with FMath library ?

Comment: @juzo4321 convert degrees to radians and try again.

Comment: @juzo4321 also, 0.73 is somewhere close to 45 degrees. 10 degrees will give an answer close to 0.

Comment: Yes it require Radians so now it gives proper result but problem is with negative angles for example if it fires from 100 height with -20 angle  and 10 velocity I get negative results

Comment: @juzo4321 the formula cannot give a negative result for positive height. Maybe there is a wrong sign somewhere in your implementation. Compare your implementation with my formula.

Comment: yes I made a mistake the angle was positive but height negative. Anyway I am working in 3D space so I need also negative heights which give me wrong results

Comment: @juzo4321 When you fire a shell from negative height, it may never reach zero height or may reach it twice. Find both roots of the equation. Positive roots mean moments when it will reach zero height. Negative ones mean moments in the past, if we extend the trajectory back. No roots means that it can't and never could reach target height.

Comment: so when I fire from negative heights I should use formula with negative Vy and when from positive the formula with pisitive Vy ?

Comment: @juzo4321 it is one and the same formula. Use the one which calculates both roots (*t1, t2 = ...*). You decide which root to use, and there may be none, because if you throw a stone down from negative height, it obviously will not reach *h = 0*.

Comment: Okey now I got it . Thank you so much !!!